# Amount Calculation using Precision

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a salary table which has `Amount` and `Amount Precision` columns.

Using precision I want to get the actual amount.

[image]

Please help me to calculate actual amount using precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
select CAST(Amount as double precision) / power(10,  AmountPrecision) from AmountTest
```

Assuming AmountTest is the name of the table. You can replace it with the name given by you.

Answer (score 5):

use [`POWER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The multiplication with `1.0` is required to convert your `Amount` in `integer` into `decimal`

```
ActualAmount = Amount * 1.0 / Power(10, AmountPrecision)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
   Amount INT,
   AmountPrecision INT
) 

INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1,1),(51,1),(51,2),(934,3),(1024,2)
SELECT 
   *,
   CAST(AMOUNT AS FLOAT)/(CONCAT(1,REPLICATE(0,AMOUNTPRECISION))) AS ACTUALAMOUNT
FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the divide by just creating value using `REPLICATE()` function.

```
CREATE TABLE Data (id int, AmountPrecision int)
INSERT INTO Data (id, AmountPrecision) VALUES
  (1, 1)
 , (51, 1)
 , (51, 2)
 , (934, 3)
 , (1024, 2)

Select id
   , Cast('1' + REPLICATE('0', AmountPrecision) as int) as DivideBy
   , Cast(id * 1.0 / Cast('1' + REPLICATE('0', AmountPrecision) as int)
   as float) as FormattedNumber
from Data
```

[image]
Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed6d31835c7dfdaff18e33e983045e34) demo.